# How can I implement a typed "both" function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, storybook

The storybook [actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-actions) addon provides a convenient way to log callback invocations:

```
renderButton({onClick: action('onClick')});
```

The `action` call returns a function that logs the string (`onClick`) and the arguments with which it's invoked.

Sometimes I want to have both the `action` and something else:

```js
renderButton({
  onClick: (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    action('onClick')(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    // ... my code
  }
});
```

The `action` call has gotten more verbose since I have to pass in all the arguments. So I've implemented a `both` function to let me write:

```js
renderButton({
  onClick: both(action('onClick'), (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    // ... my code
  })
});
```

This works great until I try to add TypeScript types. Here's my implementation:

```
function both<T extends unknown[], This extends unknown>(
  a: (this: This, ...args: T) => void,
  b: (this: This, ...args: T) => void,
): (this: This, ...args: T) => void {
  return function(this: This, ...args: T) {
    a.apply(this, args);
    b.apply(this, args);
  };
}
```

This type checks and works at runtime, but depending on the context, it either results in unwanted `any` types or type errors. For example:

```
const fnWithCallback = (cb: (a: string, b: number) => void) => {};

fnWithCallback((a, b) => {
  a;  // type is string
  b;  // type is number
});

fnWithCallback(
  both(action('callback'), (a, b) => {
    a;  // type is any
    b;  // type is any
  }),
);

fnWithCallback(
  both(action('callback'), (a, b) => {
//                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '(a: T[0], b: T[1]) => number' is not assignable to
// parameter of type '() => void'.
  }),
);
```

Is it possible to have `both` correctly capture argument types from the callback context? And to avoid the `any` types that presumably come arise from the [`action` declaration](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/0b55a323e3f3a8f3c4a5e8887e22adf5d47b7969/addons/actions/src/models/HandlerFunction.ts#L1):

```
export type HandlerFunction = (...args: any[]) => void;
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=46&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIzlAFgHgCqIKYAeUeYAJgM6LgDWYcA7mANoC6ANItujJYcWZRp1GAPgAUAKESIAhgC5EYjDwVceHAHRaZAJwDm5VQEpEAXhGIAbnBik2UlAqXdDnF5u37X2E+as27CSMnZW93RC0NXQNjMwtrW0QAbwcdPCgQHSRQSFgEZxU3dQjPGM4TFOlpGSiAB1qAGwBPAvIOaPIjAG4HaWQ6xpbQ9q9uhwBfHvGJCQgEcihEYDAAdRgMAGEZBobkGQhqM0UIZCd5RAWdGDA9DlPEMBAAW2Q8HV94gI-kxEmZ5bWm22u321DEYhkd2+lVkXWkAHp4YgoE1anhEDwLlArjcHMg4YhEcjUejMY8Xm8JOMxhIAet0FsdnsDpI+mh0ODob8OBCoXFkr1CUiqiKRQA-CWSqViwVEgCC+meJEWcGAxLRiAA5K0FEIGGB2qomAAGdiOThMACMLG+CVImoxlDoixk5HIMD0YBkyAaeFlSKgcEQtV0Mie6TeiFV6vR2tCurAtH1toCmo0EyM9hpdKBTNBrJQ7PBkJQ0P9iGllfLCr0SrAKrVKI1cZcCaTjENFtNdyN1pTtgdZLQsjdHq9Pr9IqJgeDofDxB0UcbJK1OqoieEYH79vT0nGPK51KzPQkTfRAAkZGRfToAGLgaDwJCmRSRDoKK9NVjbnqkPAQBpdHRHJHwQWRQLAMQvXDBRLmuPRgkQS9rzee9cifE8cwZYFmTBPEi0FfY8kgzUIBw0FNUzQVeVLfkYRFGQCWnFdMU-QU+iYgMWMoNiRX3BwjCCCQgA) with the full example.

Comment: @CRice see the answer below — never underestimate TypeScript! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work and keep correct callback argument types:

```
type UniversalCallback<Args extends any[]> = (...args: Args) => void;
function both<
    Args extends any[],
    CB1 extends UniversalCallback<Args>,
    CB2 extends UniversalCallback<Args>
>(fn1: CB1, fn2: CB2): UniversalCallback<Args> {
  return (...args:Args) => {
    fn1(...args);
    fn2(...args);
  };
}
```

This solution ignores `this` but I don't know if it's a problem for you because the examples of usage you gave didn't really use `this`.

It's easy enough to extend support to passing `this` to callbacks:

```
type UniversalCallback<T, Args extends any[]> = (this:T, ...args: Args) => void;
function both<
    T,
    Args extends any[],
    CB1 extends UniversalCallback<T, Args>,
    CB2 extends UniversalCallback<T, Args>
>(fn1: CB1, fn2: CB2): UniversalCallback<T, Args> {
  return function(this:T, ...args:Args) {
    fn1.apply(this, args);
    fn2.apply(this, args);
  };
}
```

It works perfectly in the following test:

```
class A { f() {} }

const fnWithCallback = (cb: (this: A, a: string, b: number) => void) => { };

fnWithCallback(function(a, b) {
  a;  // type is string
  b;  // type is number
  this.f(); // works
});

fnWithCallback(
  both(function (a) {
    a; // correct type
    this.f(); // works
  }, function (a, b) {
    a; b; // correct types
    this.f(); // works
  }),
);
```

Comment: This is great! So the essential change is to capture the type of each callback as a generic parameter?

Comment: @danvk Yes, especially the callback that `both()` is supposed to return. Then you just make the callbacks of its parameters that, or something simpler (less parameters, more universal parameters) with the use of `extends`.